# helm search and fetch not showing updated chart after upload to chartmuseum

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am using **Helm** to manage services in a **Kubernetes** cluster and use a **chartmuseum** to manage charts of my services.

After I've added the repo with the command `helm repo add URL`, helm can interact with my repo, e.g. install available charts with `helm install NAME`, or view all charts with `helm search`.

Now I face the following problem:

After creating or updating a new chart, I upload it with the command:
`curl --data-binary "@FILENAME.tgz" http://REPOURL:REPOPORT/api/charts`.

When I perform `helm search`, I expect to see the new chart or the updated version of the chart. This is **not** the case. Further, when I perform `helm fetch NAME`, I receive the old version of the updated chart.

In order to see the new or updated chart and use it, I have to re-add the repo (with the same name, otherwise it gets confusing).

Is there a way to refresh the list of available charts, without re-adding the repo?

Comment: Hi I am new to chartmuseum too, and after setting up chartmuseum by "helm install incubator/chartmuseum" in k8s cluster, I tried to upload chart to the museum and it returned 404 not found even if i ran it in the docker container which the museum running on. I wonder if you encounter the same problem before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The state of a repository is cached on your disk. When you update the remote repository you need to run `helm repo update` to retrieve the update before you can access it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can I use this command to generate such a file from the `chartmuseum`? It seems this command only enables to create such a file for a local directory (since I have to define one as command). The parameters `--url` and `--host` don't do the expected.

Comment: Do I have to fetch all charts, modify or create the one that I need, and then build the index file? Or do I have to connect to the chartmuseum-server to create the file? Or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: @ThomasBöhm Did you run `helm repo update` before `helm fetch ...`?

Comment: This is exactly what i searched for, I overlooked that option, since I didn't call `--help` on the relevant sub-command. Thank you very much! Would you add the `helm repo update` to your answer? This is exactly what solves my question.